# Is there a way to retroactively add attribute_sets to simple products?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, simple-product

All of the products in my store are created automatically by our stock control programme, which means that they are created as simple products with no attribute_sets. 
I now want to create configurable products to associate some of the individual simple products to. For example we have gloves of different sizes in stock and I have created an attribute_set of glove sizes and created a configurable parent product so customers can choose size from a dropdown which will then pick the associated child product.

Is there a way I can do this without having to recreate the simple products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to your database (CLI or PHPmyAdmin, other method)

1. Retrieve your attribute_set_id

   SELECT * FROM eav_attribute_set WHERE entity_type_id = 4;

Result like :

```
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
| attribute_set_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_name | sort_order |
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
|                4 |              4 | Default            |          1 |
|                9 |              4 | my_attr_set        |          0 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
```

2. Find all the product IDs that you want to update
3. Update

   UPDATE catalog_product_entity set attribute_set_id = {attr_set_id here} WHERE entity_id IN ({products_ids here});

**{attr_set_id here}** the attribute set id found in step 1

**{products_ids here}** product ids separated by a comma. ex. `IN (12,13,14,128,129);`

Answer (score 0):

You can mass import in backend with CSV files.

Export all your simple products, edit the CSV file to set the attributes values, then import it.

1. Go to **system** -> **import/export** -> **export**

   - Entity type : Products
   - Format : CSV

   Set the filter to limit the export to the products you want then... click **continue**
2. Edit the file you've downloaded and change the attributes values
3. Go to **system** -> **import/export** -> **export**

   - Entity type : Products
   - Beahvior : Append
   - Your edited file

Comment: I've done that now, changed the attribute_set to match that of the configurable product, imported it to the site, re-indexed the site, cleared and flushed the cache, to no avail. Am I missing a step here or am I missing something else?

Comment: Not sure you can change the attribute_set in import.

Comment: In that case, what is it I need to change to retroactively add attributes to simple products so they can be linked to a configurable product?

Comment: Just realised my question wasn't clear about what I wanted to edit and I have updated it accordingly

Comment: I thought you want to update attributes on a large amount of product. But in fact, just to be sure, you need to set an **attribute_set** to uncomplete products, is that right ?

Comment: The products aren't necessarily incomplete, but rather each individual size has a different SKU and is set up as a different Simple Product. What I want to do is retroactively add an attribute_set to a product after the product has been created, so I can then create a configurable product which I can then associate the simple products to.